# When inserting data into the database I get an error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String or binary data would be truncated.

This is my code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into students (S_username,S_password,S_f_name,S_m_name,S_l_name,S_father_name,S_mother_name,S_dob,S_gender,S_cast_id,S_religion,S_father_occu,S_mothers_occu,S_annual_income,S_local_add,S_p_address,S_L_pincode,S_p_pincode,S_L_city,S_p_city,S_L_state,S_p_state,S_department,S_semistor,s_mob_no,s_parents_mob_no,s_email,S_aadhar_no) values ('" + txtuName.Text + "','" + txtpass.Text + "','" + Txtfname.Text + "','" + Txtmname.Text + "', '" + Txtlname.Text + "','" + TxtFthname.Text + "','" + Txtmname.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value + "', '" + DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + txtrel.Text + "','" + Txtfoccu.Text + "','" + Txtmoccu .Text + "','" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "','" + Txtlcaladd.Text + "','" + TxtpAdd.Text + "','" + Txtzipcode.Text + "', '" + Txtzipc.Text + "','" + Txtcity.Text + "', '" + Textcity.Text + "', '" + Txtstate.Text + "', '" + Textstate.Text + "', '" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value + "', '" + Txtsem.Text + "','" + Txtmb.Text + "','" + Txtparmb + "','" + TxtEmail.Text + "','" + TxtAdhno.Text + "')", con);

con.Open();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

txtuName.Text = string.Empty;
txtpass.Text = string.Empty;
Txtfname.Text = string.Empty;
Txtmname.Text = string.Empty;
Txtlname.Text = String.Empty;
TxtFthname.Text = String.Empty;
Txtmname.Text = String.Empty;
TextBox2.Text = String.Empty;

DropDownList2.DataTextField = "TextFiled";
DropDownList.DataTextField = "TextFiled";

txtrel.Text = string.Empty;
Txtfoccu.Text = string.Empty;
Txtmoccu.Text = string.Empty;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "TextValues";

Txtlcaladd.Text = string.Empty;
TxtpAdd.Text = string.Empty;
Txtzipcode.Text = string.Empty;
Txtzipc.Text = string.Empty;
Txtcity.Text = string.Empty;
Textcity.Text = string.Empty;
Txtstate.Text = string.Empty;
Textstate.Text = string.Empty;
DropDownList3.DataTextField = "TextFiled";
Txtsem.Text = string.Empty;

// objnew.lastAppointmentNo = Convert.ToInt32(Request["txtLastAppointmenNo"]);
int s_mob_no = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("s_mob_no"));
int s_parents_mob_no = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get(" s_parents_mob_no"));
//Txtmb.Text = string.Empty;
// Txtparmb.Text = string.Empty;
TxtEmail.Text = string.Empty;
int S_aadhar_no = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get(" S_aadhar_no"));

con.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Success");
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: You will use try catch block for handling Exception'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to do here:

1. Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection:

   ```
   string query = "insert into students (username, ...) VALUES(@uname, ...)";           
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

   //Passing values to Parameters
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", "Value");
   ```
2. Check the parameter values are in accordance with the  columns in your SQL table both datatype and size. I think it is the size which is causing the problem in your case. You are trying to insert data that has a greater length than what you have defined for that column in the SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

> use parametrized queries so you avoid SQL Injection attacks

```
        //Replaced Parameters with Value
        string query = "insert into students (S_username, ...) VALUES(@username, ...)";           
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        //Pass values to Parameters
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", "XYZ_Value");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@...", "$20");
```